# What is ORRr instruction do in ARM

Tags: arm

I am not able to understand below command used in cache initialization.
inv_loop2
        LSL r3, r1, r6
        LSL r8, r2, r7
        ORRr 3, r3, r8

In this how ORRr work?  I know about ORR instruction but ORRr is quite confusing

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? ORRr 3, r3, r8 == ORR r3, r3, r8

Comment: I am not sure but it is documented in ARM site

Comment: It's a typo. "3" is hardly a valid destination operand either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo.

You are looking at an old version of the documentation for enabling caches on ARM processors (M-7?).  The updated documentation is here, and does not contain the same typo:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0646b/BABGJGCH.html